# How can I write these variables into one line of code in C#?

Tags: c#, console, int, var, console.writeline

I am new to C#, literally on page 50, and i am curious as to how to write these variables in one line of code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace consoleHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int mon = DateTime.Today.Month;
            int da = DateTime.Today.Day;
            int yer = DateTime.Today.Year;
            var time = DateTime.Now;

            Console.Write(mon);
            Console.Write("." + da);
            Console.WriteLine("." + yer);
        }
    }
}
```

I am coming from JavaScript where to do this it would look like this:

```
document.write(mon+'.'+da+'.'+yer);
```

Any help here is appreciated.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Look into [composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}", mon, da, yer);
```

You could also write (although it's not really recommended):

```
Console.WriteLine(mon + "." + da + "." + yer);
```

And, with the release of C# 6.0, you have string interpolation expressions:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{mon}.{da}.{yer}");  // note the $ prefix.
```

Comment: why is the second way not recommended?

Comment: OK great! Thanks I haven't gotten to composite formatting. but I was not closing the ToString with () thus the issue. I am still on types right now but this is valuable insight moving forward...

Comment: @AStidham: Not recommended because it's longer, more difficult to see what's going on, more difficult to modify, and less amenable to internationalization.

Comment: @Servy: Good catch. I didn't realize that the compiler would do that. Shows you how often I do string concatenation, doesn't it?

Comment: It's not really the compiler.  The `operator +` has three overloads for string concatenation: (string, string), (string, object), and (object, string).  The rest of the overloads involve both parameters being numeric types.  For the 2nd and 3rd overloads it just calls `ToString` on the object (after null checking it) in the body of the definition.

Comment: This is ultimately what I was trying earlier and the problem was that if a string is not separating the int's they would add together. This is why I like the top method more. Thanks guys for your input

Comment: I don't have enough rep to do that yet, I have to have 15 points and I only have 11, If you vote up my question then I might have enough to go through them all and up vote them

Comment: Just going back looking at old questions and now that i have enough rep I marked it correct. Thanks Jim!

Answer (score 17):

You can do your whole program in one line!  Yes, that is right, one line!

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd"));
```

You may notice that I did not use the same date format as you.  That is because you should use the **International Date Format** as described in [this W3C document](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/iso-date).  Every time you don't use it, somewhere a cute little animal dies.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't notice.  Will amend this response to chastise him for his poor choice of date format.

Comment: Not just a single line, but a single function call :) Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy.MM.dd}", DateTime.Now);

Comment: And every time you try to force the International Date Format on a client who wants MM/DD/YYYY, you lose a job.

Comment: for the cute little animals everywhere

Answer (score 8):

You can do pretty much the same as in JavaScript. Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(mon + "." + da + "." + yer);
```

Or you can use `WriteLine` as if it were a `string.Format` statement by doing:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}", mon, da, yer);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}", mon, da, yer);
```

The number of parameters can be infinite, just make sure you correctly index those numbers (starting at 0).

Answer (score 5):

You should try this one:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}", mon, da, yet);
```

See http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-writeline for more details.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use something similar to the JavaScript, you just need to convert to strings first:

```
Console.WriteLine(mon.ToString() + "." + da.ToString() + "." + yer.ToString());
```

But a (much) better way would be to use the format option:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}.{1}.{2}", mon, da, yer);
```

Comment: OK great! Thanks I haven't gotten to composite formatting. but I was not closing the ToString with () thus the issue. I am still on types right now but this is valuable insight moving forward...

Answer (score 1):

You could theoretically do the entire thing as simply:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;

namespace consoleHelloWorld {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
       Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy"));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes that's great but I wanted to break up the date and get the numbers individually first then reassemble them but you are absolutely right

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateTime dateTime = dateTime.Today.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");

 Console.Write(dateTime);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use $ before " " it will allow to write variables between these brackets

```
 Console.WriteLine($"{mon}.{da}.{yer}");
```

The pro way :

```
  Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Today.Month}.{DateTime.Today.Day}.{DateTime.Today.Year}");
  Console.WriteLine($"month{DateTime.Today.Month} day{DateTime.Today.Day} year{DateTime.Today.Year}");
```

5.24.2016

month5 day24 year2016

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```
string format = "{0} / {1} / {2} {3}";
string date = string.Format(format,mon.ToString(),da.ToString(),yer.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

In fact, there's probably a way to format it automatically without even doing it yourself.

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy");
```

link to MSDN on ALL formatting options for DateTime.ToString() method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: This did though:             DateTime thisDate1 = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Today is " + thisDate1.ToString("MMMM dd, yyyy") + ".");